# Injection doesn't work in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm doing a web app with Angular 1 using Typescript. I have to create a Factory in which I have some conditions in which I want to inject some dependences. This is the code:

```
.factory('myFactory', function ($q: angular.IQService, $location: ng.ILocationService, $localStorage: any, Ob: any, $injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService) {
        return {
        f: function (config: any) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if (Ob.auth) {
                let $state = $injector.get("$state");
                $state.go("app.auth");
            }
            return config;
        },
   .... other methods....
        };
})
```

When I compile I have this error in console:

```
ts\inj.ts(110,14): error TS2339: Property 'go' does not exist on type '{}'.
ts\inj.ts(126,13): error TS2339: Property 'go' does not exist on type '{}'.
[10:46:55] TypeScript: 2 semantic errors
[10:46:55] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this page](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/angularjs--angular-route/interfaces/ng.auto.iinjectorservice.html#get) it doesn't look like the $state object has a `go()` method, which is why TypeScript is throwing an error. Did you mean to use `$state.get()` instead?

Comment: i want to redirect the user to that state, and with 'get' it gives me the same error

Comment: Exactly the same error on exactly the same lines even if you replace them with `get`? even if there is no `go` in your code anymore?